# InApp purchase version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

We are facing following issue regarding InApp purchase version 3

In log error:

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase version3

InApp:

> the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

Comment: So...you entered your products in the developer console?

Comment: Yes we have enter product on Developer console we have wait 24 hours but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following points:-

1. The version code of the app is same as uploaded in alpha/beta/production version.
2. You have checked the app to be available in All Countries.
3. If published in alpha/beta then the google account used in downloading the app is in tester list & License accounts.
4. Package name is same of app published in playstore and app running in your device.